# std::logic error while running .exe file

Tags: c++, string

I am getting this std::logic error while running .exe file

```
basic string::_S_construct null not valid
```

And I have searched forums and looked and looked everywhere and I am not seeing where I passed the null reference to the string constructor, can anyone shine light for me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Attendance        //parent class called Attendance
{
  public:
     Attendance() : name("Not Assigned"), id(0), num_modules(0),num_contact_hours(0), num_attended(0) { }       //default constructor
     //below is a constructor 
     Attendance(string n, string id, int num_mod, int num_hours, int num_att) : name(n), id(id), num_modules(num_mod), num_contact_hours(num_hours), num_attended(num_att) { }
      ~Attendance() { } //destructor

  // you place your other functions here...

  protected:
     string name;       //name of person
     string id;         //staff or studentid
     int num_modules, num_contact_hours, num_attended;  //the array contains the number of hours in the first sem and second sem
};



class Staff : public Attendance     //subclass for Staff attendace
{
public:
   void initialize_staff(string, string, int, int, int, int, int);
   Staff() : lecture_hours(16), type("Full time") { }       //default constructor, default lecturing hours should be 16
   Staff(string n, string id, int mod, int contact, int attend, int hours, string t) : Attendance(n, id, num_modules, num_contact_hours, num_attended), lecture_hours(hours), type(t) { }
   ~Staff() { }     //destructor
   void setLecturingHours(int hours) { lecture_hours = hours; } //member function (mutator) of subclass that sets lecture hours
   int LecturingHours() { return lecture_hours; }       //accessor function that returns the lecturer hours
   void setType(string t) { type = t; }     //mutator function for 
   string Lecturer_Type() { return type; }  
   void initialize_staff(string,string,int,int,int,string);
   void add();
   void display();
   bool find_free_pos();
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Staff& staff_);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Staff& staff);
private:
    int lecture_hours;
   string type;  // full time or part-time
};

class Student : public Attendance
{
   public:
    Student() : type("Undefined") {}
    Student(string n, string id, int mod, int attend, int hours, string t) : Attendance(n, id, mod, num_contact_hours, attend), type(t) {}
    ~Student() {};
    void initialize_student(string,string,int,int,int,string);
    void add();
    void display();
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, Student& student_);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Student& student);
    bool find_free_pos();

    void setContactHours(int hours) {};
    int getContactHours() {return num_contact_hours;};


   private:
    string type;
    // you populate your variables here
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int i=0, choice_task_menu=0, position=0, num_attend=0, num_modules=0, choice_search, num_contact_hours, lecture_hours;      //variables
    string name, id, type;


    Student *student; //declaring pointer called student that will point to object of class Student
    student = new Student[50];  //object created in dynamic memory

    Staff *staff;       //declaring pointer called staff that will point to object of class Staff
    staff = new Staff[50];  //object created in dynamic memory


    Staff staf_count;   //variables just to count the number of rows in file and do nothing else
    Student stud_count; //variables just to count number of rows in file

    ifstream fin1, fin2, fin3, fin4;                // input file stream, fin1 declared
    fin1.open("attendance_student.txt", ios::in);       //open a text file named "student_attendance.txt"
    if(fin1.fail())             //if it fails, output the following and exit the programs
    {
    cout << "Error opening file for reading\n";
    exit(1);
    }

    int count_student = 0, count_staff = 0;             //initialize count to zero
    while(fin1 >> stud_count) // while true (there are values to read in), exucute the loop again           |{line includes call to overloading operators}|
    {                   
        count_student++;                //post-increment the count each time the 6 variables (a row) are filled
    }
    fin1.close();           //close file
    cout << "the number of rows in the students file: " << count_student << endl;


    fin2.open("attendance_staff.txt", ios::in);     //open a text file named "staff_attendance.txt"
    if(fin2.fail())             //if it fails, output the following and exit the programs
    {
    cout << "Error opening file for reading\n";
    exit(1);
    }

    count_staff = 0;                //initialize count to zero
    while(fin2 >> staf_count) // while true (there are values to read in), exucute the loop again           |{line includes call to overloading operators}|
    {                   
        count_staff++;              //post-increment the count each time the 6 variables (a row) are filled
    }
    fin2.close();           //close file
    cout << "the number of rows in the staff file: " << count_staff << endl;

    fin3.open("attendance_student.txt", ios::in);       //opens file named "phonebook.txt"
    if(fin1.fail())         //if it fails to open file, display the following and exits program
    {
    cout << "Error opening file for reading\n";
    exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;              //read the contents in to myphbk now
    while(fin3 >> student[i] && i < count_student)
    {   
    i++;    
    }

    for(i=0;i<50;i++)       //displays every student
    student[i].display();

    //now it will operate the staff

    fin4.open("attendance_staff.txt", ios::in);     //opens file named "phonebook.txt"
    if(fin4.fail())         //if it fails to open file, display the following and exits program
    {
    cout << "Error opening file for reading\n";
    exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;              //read the contents in to myphbk now
    while(fin4 >> staff[i] && i < count_staff)
    {   
    i++;    
    }

    for(i=0;i<50;i++)       //displays every contact
    staff[i].display();


    //overloading operators later 




    int pos = 0;
    for(pos = 0; pos < 50; pos++)           // initializing everything to undefined, and position to free (position is the second parameter sended in)  
    {
        //the sequence goes like this (name,id,num_modules,num_contact_hours,num_attend,type)
        student[pos].initialize_student( "Undefined", "0", 0, 0, 0,"Undefined");    //initialize everything to zero and strings are undefined
        staff[pos].initialize_staff("Undefined", "0",0 ,0,0, "Undefined");
        //void Student::initialise(string name_,string id_, int num_modules_, int num_contact_hours_, int num_attended_, int type_)
        //void Staff::initialise(string name_, string id_, int num_modules_, int lecture_hours_, int num_attended_, string type_)
        //take previous two comments away

    }

    cout << "Please select option (1. Add a person/2. Search for a person)" << endl;
    cin >> choice_task_menu;    //menu only gives 2 choices (add or search for an individual)

    switch(choice_task_menu)
    {
        case(1):    // add a person, now its classified staff or student
            cout << "Please enter the position of the person (1. Staff/ 2. Student)" << endl;
            cin >> position;



            //if 1, call staff initialize function, if 2, call student initialize function
            if(position == 1)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                {   
                    if(student[i].find_free_pos())
                    {
                        student[i].add();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

            if(position == 2)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
                {
                    if(student[i].find_free_pos())
                    {
                        student[i].add();
                    }
                }
            }
        case(2):
            cout << "How do you want to search (1. Name/2. ID)" << endl;
            cin >> choice_search;
    }

    return 0;
}

void Student::initialize_student(string name_,string id_, int num_modules_, int num_contact_hours_, int num_attended_, string type_)
{
    //now assign them to private member variables
    name = name_;
    id = id_;
    num_modules = num_modules_;
    num_contact_hours = num_contact_hours_;
    type = type_;
    num_attended = num_attended_;


    //end of assigning
}

void Staff::initialize_staff(string name_, string id_, int num_modules_, int lecture_hours_, int num_attended_, string type_)
{
    //assigning to private member variables
    name = name_;
    id = id_;
    num_modules = num_modules_;
    type = type_;
    num_attended = num_attended_;
    lecture_hours = lecture_hours_;

}

bool Student::find_free_pos()
{
    if (name == "Undefined")
    {
        return true;
    }
}

bool Staff::find_free_pos()
{
    if (name == "Undefined")
    {
        return true;
    }
}

void Student::add()
{
            cout << "Please enter the type of the person (Full time/Part Time)" << endl;
            cin >> type;
            cout << "Please enter name of person you wish to add" << endl;
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Please enter the ID of the person" << endl;
            cin >> id;      //remember that id is type string
            cout << "Please enter number of contact hours" << endl;
            cin >> num_contact_hours;
            cout << "Please enter number of hours that the person attended" << endl;
            cin >> num_attended;
            cout << "Please enter the number of modules that the person has" << endl;
            cin >> num_modules;
}

void Staff::add()
{
            cout << "Please enter the type of the person (Full time/Part Time)" << endl;
            cin >> type;
            cout << "Please enter name of person you wish to add" << endl;
            cin >> name;
            cout << "Please enter the ID of the person" << endl;
            cin >> id;      //remember that id is type string
            cout << "Please enter number of hours that the person attended" << endl;
            cin >> num_attended;
            cout << "Please enter the number of modules that the person has" << endl;
            cin >> num_modules;
            cout << "Please enter lecture hours (if any)" << endl;
            cin >> lecture_hours;
}

void Student::display()
{
    cout << name << " " << type << " " << id << " " << num_contact_hours << " " <<  num_modules << " " << num_attended;
}

void Staff::display()
{
    cout << name << " " << type << " " << id << " " << lecture_hours << " " <<  num_modules << " " << num_attended;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& in , Staff& staff)       //overloading operator on insertion operator
{
    in >> staff.name >> staff.type >> staff.id >> staff.lecture_hours >> staff.num_modules >> staff.num_attended;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out , Staff& staff)      //overloading operator on extraction operator
{
    out << staff.name << staff.type << staff.id << staff.lecture_hours << staff.num_modules << staff.num_attended;
    return out;
} 

istream& operator >> (istream& in , Student& student)       //overloading operator on insertion operator
{
    in >> student.name >> student.type >> student.id >> student.num_contact_hours >> student.num_modules >> student.num_attended;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out , Student& student)      //overloading operator on extraction operator
{
    out << student.name << student.type << student.id << student.num_contact_hours << student.num_modules << student.num_attended;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger. It will tell you where.

Comment: `std::logic_error` in the standard library should only happen if your program has undefined behaviour. And if that's the case then the error message might not tell you the actual problem. Can you try providing a simpler example that triggers the error?

Comment: oh by the way I have two void initialize_staff member functions, I'm aware of that, I took the top one away from the class and it still wouldn't work

Comment: the error doesnt show up in my debugger in my compiler, it displays the error on my .exe

Comment: @user4364503, A debugger is used with an executable at runtime, not with a compiler. Unrelated to that, I get a [ton of warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac2513bd2408aba5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is triggerred when you are trying to construct (hence `_S_construct`) a `string` (hence `basic_string`) initializing it to `NULL` (ie. the constant `(char const *) NULL`).

Here, the first item I could find like this in your code is in `Attendance::Attendance` where you initialize `id` to `0` (that is equivalent to initializing to `NULL`).

There is no typing error since 0 is a pointer to a constant character string, but a special check has been placed to avoid a segmentation fault that would occur if it actually tried to read the string at position 0.

The most likely fix would be to replace `id(0)` with `id("")`, and the same thing everywhere you try to initialize a `std::string` to `NULL` (or `0`).

Comment: Thank you kind sir! You have gave me new knowledge today as a rookie! I fixed it! I wish I had 15 rep so i could upvote your answer

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, you can still accept my answer, as this will mark your question as solved. And do not forget to hunt for any compiler warnings, as they most likely indicate some error somewhere down your code paths.